# Shell script - bad interpreter: Operation not permitted

Tags: macos, script

I put the below script in a file called "volume", and put that file in a folder within $PATH.
I can execute it fine by "bash thatpath/volume 10" but when I try to execute it using just "volume 10" from anywhere I get "/bin/bash: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted". The file's permissions are 755.

```
#!/bin/sh

FIRST_ARGUMENT="$1"
echo "Set volume to $FIRST_ARGUMENT!"
osascript -e "set volume output volume $FIRST_ARGUMENT"
```

Comment: Is the FS mounted `noexec`? Is it possible the file has Windows line endings (CR+LF instead of just LF)? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6821/bash-wont-execute-files

Comment: I read some similar issue and they also noted that the line endings might be messed up. So I started a new file and typed that all once more and saved. +x:ed it and it started working. So I guess yes, the line endings were the culprit. I did edit the file first time with TextEdit, it shouldn't give Windows line endings but um anyway it's fixed now.

Comment: The `strings` command should help you fix the issue without having to manually type the whole file again.

Comment: Jonny, you should answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read some similar issue and they also noted that the line endings might be messed up. So I started a new file and typed that all once more and saved. +x:ed it and it started working. So I guess yes, the line endings were the culprit. I did edit the file first time with TextEdit, it shouldn't give Windows line endings but um anyway it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I hit this on my Mac after renaming a shell file in Finder that was open in BBEdit. Then, when I modified the file in BBEdit (which correctly reflected the new filename) and saved, I could no longer run the script.

For me, the fix was as simple as quitting BBEdit and re-launching, then saving the file once more. ‍♂️

My issue was happening regardless of whether or not arguments were included.